# How can get all the instance's specifications with AWS JAVA API

Tags: java, aws-sdk

Now i have got the instance's type for example "t2.micro".

And the question is how can i got the info like this:

[image]

Comment: [EC2 Describe Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html)

Comment: `DescribeInstance` describes a specific instance, not the general specification of instance type `t2.micro` in this case. Don't think there is an AWS supported API for retrieving that information.

Comment: So the question is "How to get all instance types"

Comment: Thank you, friend! My goal is to finish using API to open an instance, and now I start to understand, maybe I need to start from AMI

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to look at all the image! Although it is not very useful, it also needs to be recorded.

```
    DescribeImagesResult describeImagesRequest = ec2Client.describeImages();
    List<Image> imageList = describeImagesRequest.getImages();
    for(Image image : imageList){

        System.out.println(image);
    }
```